Use the decorate function and mark points on a curve to draw tangents
I am trying to draw tangent for simple curve (f(x) = x^2) with using of decoration={markings, mark= at position #1 with {...}}(see How to get a tangent coordinate system for the decoration of a path?). But Unfortunately, the code works correctly until I change the y-axis range in axis environment. The code ymin = -1.5, ymax = 4, affected the slope of the lines (see figure below)

It seems that changing the range of axes, can affect the position of the tangents, because the decoration of the tangents are defined relative to the original scale of the graph. When I change ymin and ymax, I guess I'm also changing the scale at which the tangents are drawn, which may cause them not to appear in the expected places.
I tried to save the code by adding a line:
/pgf/decoration/transform={scale=1}

but without success.
MNWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, scale=1, 
  tangent/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,% switch on markings
      mark=
        at position #1
        with
        {
          \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number})
           at (0pt,0pt);
          \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
          \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1);
        }
      },
      postaction=decorate,
      % /pgf/decoration/transform={scale=1}  % <- not working solution
  },
  use tangent/.style={
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)
  },
  use tangent/.default=1,
  myarrow/.style={-{Latex[round, scale=2.5, length=2, width=3]}}
]

  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,
    xmin = -2.5, xmax = 2.5, 
    % ymin = -1.5, ymax = 4,      % <- the source of the problem
    grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
    major grid style={solid, line width=.4pt, draw=gray!60},
    minor grid style={solid, line width=.2pt, draw=gray!30},
    minor tick num=5,
    grid = both,   % both, major
    clip = true,
    clip mode =individual,
    axis x line = middle, 
    axis y line = middle,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(y\)}
  ]
        
    \addplot[
      name path global=fx,
      color=Coral4,
      smooth, ultra thick, 
      tangent=0.224,
      tangent=0.659,
      no markers
    ] gnuplot{x^2};  
    
    \draw [
      black, thick,
      use tangent=1
    ] (-.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw [
      black, thick,
      use tangent=2
    ] (-.5,0) -- (0.5,0);


    \node[below left] at (0,0) {\(0\)};
    \node[right, Coral4] at (-1.8,3.4) {\(\boldsymbol{g(x) = x^2}\)};
    \fill [black] (+1,1) circle (1mm);
    \fill [black] (-1.41421,2) circle (1mm);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You need to link or write from where you got the code. -you did not write it yourself. You do not need or want gnuplot for this.
The problem is that you you define your tangent space in a stretched coordinate system. To avoid this, simply use units like this:
  \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
  \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1cm,0pt);
  \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1cm);



link to source code is added. Thanks a lot for your help.
